# FOR NEXT or FOR EACH LOOP only works for first value

Tags: vba, excel

***Please help in making the For Next Loop for the following code;***
I'm trying to copy each cell in a range & past it to specific (fixed position) cell then copy the results from a specific (fixed position) cells and paste it certain cells. I want to do it for for each cell in a range. Using Macro i recorded the code below which worked perfect but i want to make a For NEXT or FOR EACH loop from this recorded macro, so please anyone help me.

'

```
' PastSpecialCheck6 Macro
'

' For L1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(12, 103).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B9").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("B28:B34").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Cells(40, 103).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
' For L02
    ActiveSheet.Cells(13, 103).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B9").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("B28:B34").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Cells(40, 104).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
' For L03
    ActiveSheet.Cells(14, 103).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B9").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("B28:B34").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Cells(40, 105).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

I tried this code for looping but in vain. It only works for one cell in a range.

```
  Sub pastspecialmy_30July2015_2()
 ' Ln is length
 Dim Ln As Variant
 ' i is numbers
 Dim i As Integer

 ' For L1

 For Each Ln In ActiveSheet.Range("CY12:CY30").Cells
   For i = 125 To 143
    ' Ln.Activate
    Range("B9").Select
    Selection.Value = Ln
    Range("B28:B34").Select
    Selection.Copy

    ActiveSheet.Cells(57, i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
  Next
 Next

 End Sub
```

Comment: What if you change your `For Each` to a simple for if you know how many rows there are. Does it work now ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    n = 103

    With ws
        For i = 12 To 30
            .Cells(i, 103).Copy
            .Range("B9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            .Range("B28:B34").Copy
            .Cells(40, n).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            n = n + 1
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Work Perfect, Thank you very much you have saved my time.